# Raspberry Pi 3 download menu not showing

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I just brought a raspberry pi 3 with the noobs card with pre installed raspbian l, however when I turned power the download option menu didn’t appear but instead just run. Eventually getting to the home screen.

Main question, how do I know raspbian is installed? And why would the download menu not appear?

Any help would be great as I am new with raspberry pi.

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

Hold SHIFT while booting. Download menu should show.